# Jersey error with tomcat WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I cannot get My tomcat server to work with my WAR file. 
I am using jersey 1.14 and It is running fine through tomcat 6 in eclipse. But when I upload the war to my remote tomcat 6 server I receive the following error when i try access the site.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/shafer/server/server : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.shafer.server.server)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.classForNameWithException(ReflectionHelper.java:238)
com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationScannerListener.java:222)
com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationScannerListener.java:186)
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.`
```

here is my web xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>shafer</display-name>
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
  <param-value>com.shafer.server</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your .war was compiled under a newer JDK than the JRE that is available on the remote tomcat. Either install a matching JRE on the remote server or recompile your project with the correct version of the JDK.

Comment: This was exactly the problem, I mistakenly compiled using 1.7, instead of 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

This line should give you a clou:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/shafer/server/server :
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
(unable to load class com.shafer.server.server)
```

What is `com.shafer.server.server`? Check the versions of your libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The UnsupportedClassVersionError means that the class was compiled with a more recent Java compiler than the one you are using in your runtime.

I don't know the version numbers by hearth, but you should probably use a JRE 6 or higher to run Tomcat.